# When is the quotient of a manifold by a discrete group of diffeomorphisms a diffeological covering space?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smoothness, covering-spaces, generalized-smooth-spaces, diffeology

I was reading [An Introduction to Diffeology](http://math.huji.ac.il/~piz/documents/AITD.pdf) by Patrick Iglesias-Zemmour and he defines a diffeological covering space as a diffeological fiber bundle with discrete fiber.

> My question: Consider a manifold $M$ and a discrete subgroup $G$ of $\mathrm{Diff}(M)$ acting on $M$ freely. When is the quotient morphism $M \to M/G$ a diffeological covering space?

I have the impression the answer is "For every $x\in M$, the orbit of $x$ must be discrete in $M$", but I'm not sure.

In order to prove the result I believe the strategy is to prove the map
$$G \times M \to M \times M
$$
given by 
$$(g,x) \mapsto (gx,x)$$
is a diffeomorphism to its image.

This map is injective because the action is free. Furthermore, it's smooth because the map $\mathrm{Diff}(M)\times M \to M$, given by $(g,x) \mapsto gx$, is smooth.

Observation: Every time I used the word discrete, I meant it in the diffeological sense.

Comment: By definition, diffeological covering spaces are nothing more than diffeological fiber bundles with discrete fibers. So I think your strategy is right for a partial answer, as you can see this in [Patrick Iglesias-Zemmour, Diffeology, art. 8.11], especially that your diffeological covering space would arise from group action. However, this works for any diffeological spaces, not only for manifolds.